# display as table-cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm playing around with `display` properties trying to get the hang of them.

One question I had was how to get spacing between the table cells. Right now I have 4 images that are boxed up against each other. I want to have them tight to the left side but spacing in between. So even spacing everywhere except the left. I tried to use `border-spacing: 5px;` but that added spacing on the left.

I put a version in jsfiddle but its rendering with another issue. In jsfiddle its showing space between the rows. Not sure why that's happening as its working correctly in the browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/RjGaX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add  `padding:5px 5px 5px 0;` to `#displayWrapper #grid .gridImage` to get the even padding.

This rule says add `5px` of `padding` to the `top`, `right`, and `bottom` and `0 padding` to the `left`.

Add  `img {vertical-align:bottom;}` to fix the extra space at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/RjGaX/3/

Comment: by adding padding to the gridImage it will give me spacing but the spacing will be inside the image border. I want the spacing to be outside the border.

Comment: Also how come I don't need to add img {vertical-align:bottom;} when viewed from anywhere else but jsfiddle

Comment: @Chapsterj.  Not sure about the `img` alignment outside the fiddle?  About the spacing: add `border-spacing:5px;` to your table element (`#displayWrapper #grid`). http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/RjGaX/5/  Unfortunately, this applies the spacing evenly.  If you want spacing between the images but not at the left, you will need to wrap the `img`s in a `div` and add padding to the three sides.

Comment: Thanks Jason I had already tried the border spacing but not what I'm after. As for wrapping the images in another div, isn't that what the div with the class gridImage is doing.

Comment: @Chapsterj. Yes.  But with the additional `div` you will be able to space the way you wish *and* keep the `img border` attached to the `img`, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `border-collapse:separate;` so that your `border-spacing` is actually between the borders of the two cells.

Answer (score 0):

add display: block; to the img